# There's no battery indicator in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, battery

I have a really annoying problem with battery indicator on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
If the laptop is connected to its power supply, the indicator works fine and shows the progress of charging and also discharging after I disconnect the power supply. However, if I then restart the laptop on battery, there is no battery indicator anymore (which is really annoying on a laptop...). It will return though once I connect it again to the power supply...

I have already reinstalled the service and tried several other fixes (seems to be a common problem...) from the web but so far nothing has really worked yet.

Here is a screenshot of Power Settings:

[image]

Comment: What make and model of laptop are you using? And does `upower -d` have any accurate output?

Comment: My guess is that it's an older battery that needs to be replaced.

Comment: Model of my laptop is fujitsu lifebook AH512. This is output for upower -d -> http://i.imgur.com/zXl7Ias.png

Comment: Could someone help me, please ???

Comment: When the battery is plugged in, does it show up in /sys/class/power_supply folder   ? Typically you should have two folders in power_supply, one is ACAD and BAT1 , but it could be BAT0 as well.

Comment: also, check the settings in dconf editor. com->canonical->indicator->power. Mine are: icon-policy present, show-percentage (checked); show-time (unchecked)

Comment: Try upgrading gnome shell to 3.12 using the PPA from this website: Ubuntu Gnome Staging PPA

Answer (score 0):

Your notebook is similar at mine, same Intel chipset and hardware configuration.

I went through the same problem. I thought it was poor contact of battery, but it was a bug in hardware management. I updated the UEFI firmware (ex-BIOS) and the problem disappeared.